# javascript select a specific word in string if it's the last word in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the last word in a text string *only* if the last word in the string is the word "Premium." I have no control over the HTML.

I start by adding a premium class to any link that contains the word premium:

```
$('ul.menu li > a:contains("Premium"))
        .addClass('premium');
```

And then I attempt to add a span class to the word Premium if it's the last word:

```
$('ul.menu li > a.premium')
        .html(function(idx, html){
            return html.replace(/(\w+)$/, '<span class="premium">$1</span>')
        });
```

The result that I'm getting is the last word of any list item that contains the word "Premium" anywhere in it is getting the span. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regular expression so it only matches the word `Premium`, not any word:

```
$('ul.menu li > a.premium')
    .html(function(idx, html){
        return html.replace(/\bPremium$/, '<span class="premium">&</span>')
    });
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. One slight change I had to make: I had to change `<span class="premium">$1</span>` to `<span class="premium">Premium</span>`.

Comment: That will work or you can use `&` to copy what was matched by the regexp.